# How do I render a triangle in QOpenGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to use OpenGL inside of Qt using QOpenGLWidget, but I am having a hard time finding any relevant examples. I am new to OpenGL, so I am trying to learn how to use it, but the tutorials that I find don't seem to apply particularly well in QOpenGLWidget. Right now, all I want to do is render a triangle to start with.

Here's what I have so far.

Header:

```
namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int, int);
    void paintGL();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
```

Class:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void Widget::initializeGL()
{
    // Set up the rendering context, load shaders and other resources, etc.:
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
}

void Widget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    // Update projection matrix and other size-related settings:
}

void Widget::paintGL()
{
    // Draw the scene:
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Is there any example I could use to just render a basic triangle? I tried the one from here: https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/books/openglr_es_20_programming_guide_sample.pdf, but it threw a lot of errors that I couldn't work out.

I also don't know how OpenGL contexts work in QOpenGLWidget.

*EDIT: So it turns out that the examples were a separate package on my distro (Arch Linux). I was able to install them, and it looks like there is plenty there to get started.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried studying the GL (ES) examples that are shipped with Qt? There's nothing particular about QOpenGLWidget.

Comment: Where can I find these examples?

Comment: They're shipped with Qt. OpenGL section. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets-opengl.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to use `QOpenGLWidget` not `QGLWidget`, then this is the way to do it.

Open Qt Creator and choose Qt Widgets Application. Add Widget and push button as follows

[image]

`main.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

`mainwindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Now add New Class and name it `OGLWidget` which should be inherited from `QOpenGLWidget`

`oglwidget.h`

```
#ifndef OGLWIDGET_H
#define OGLWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>

class OGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
public:
    OGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~OGLWidget();

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();
};

#endif // OGLWIDGET_H
```

`oglwidget.cpp`

```
#include "oglwidget.h"

OGLWidget::OGLWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{

}

OGLWidget::~OGLWidget()
{

}

void OGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}

void OGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0);
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f( 0.0,  0.5, 0);
    glEnd();
}

void OGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, (float)w/h, 0.01, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,0,5,0,0,0,0,1,0);
}
```

Now go back to the form and right click on the widget. Select *promoted widgets* and type in the promoted class name *OGLWidget*. Hit the add button and then promote. Now click on the background and go to its properties and change *windowModality* to ApplicationModel.

[image]

and this is the result you should get

[image]

the `.pro` file is

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-07-20T15:15:29
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    oglwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    oglwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response. Aren't glBegin and glEnd deprecated, though? Also, is GLU required?

Comment: This is a mere example. Qt has some examples in case you want more details.

Comment: This doesn't show how to use the functionality in QOpenGLWidget. If you would choose to use OpenGL like this there wouldn't be any purpose in subclassing QOpenGLWidget that I can see.

Comment: @CroCo Sorry for the necropost. Any idea why the bit with the promoted widgets would fail? It was worked fine the first time I followed your instructions; failed the 2-4th times.

Comment: What is the difference between QOpenGLWidget and QGLWidget?

Comment: @DomiDiDongo QGLWidget is for Native OpenGL implementation inside QT; It requires openGL to be installed in the compiler for it; but QT has its own implementation of openGL functions, which is in QOpenGLWidget in this case. I have encountered a problem with it previously, which was solved in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550442/qt-5-5-qopenglwidget-link-error-not-linking-any-opengl-calls/33568323#33568323

Comment: If #include <gl/GLU.h> is not found, change to #include <GL/GLU.h>. Same for #include <gl/GL.h>.

Comment: If GLPerspective or GLlookat is not recognized, apart from David Tóth answer, include "LIBS += -lglut -lGLU" into the .pro file.

Comment: This method is completely deprecated and should never, ever be used:
glBegin() / glEnd() are OpenGL1.1

QGLWidget was deprecated in Qt5 and was removed in Qt5.6