# How to enable depth test with QOpenGLWidget? It renders black screen

Tags: qt, opengl, qwidget, depth-buffer, depth-testing

Currently I am writing a small application with Qt and OpenGl and I choosed `QOpenGLWidget` for rendering graphics.

That's how I declared my widget:

```
class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions{
     // Methods, slots, e.t.c
}
```

And that's the constructor:

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    /* Tried this, it didn't help.
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    this->setFormat(format);
    */
}
```

In my init function I set `GL_CULL_FACE` and `GL_DEPTH_TEST`:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    /* Some initialization stuff regarding the scene */

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

}
```

And I really don't know why the widget renders the black screen.
Here are some pictures.
First one: with disabled `GL_CULL_FACE` and disabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST`.
[image]

Second one: with enabled `GL_CULL_FACE` and disabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST`. Maybe it's not a good picture, but I can assure you, you can see some surfaces through the other.
[image]

Third one: with enabled `GL_CULL_FACE` and enabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST`. Actually, it doesn't matter if `GL_CULL_FACE` is enabled. Anyway it renders the black screen.
[image]

And here's the image without any shading just to show you that the model is fine.
[image]

I tried to set the format manually, but it didn't help. Still the black screen:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
this->setFormat(format);
```

Oh and yes, I set `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` at the beginning of my `paintGL()` function.

Comment: By the way, if I try to set the version with `format.setVersion(3, 2);`, it also renders the black screen. I am not sure, but I think it's somehow related to the problem.

Comment: Have you tried testing your code with a simple cube? Also, I think it'd help to share your shader code and your paintGL() function. See also this reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381314/qopenglwidget-show-black-screen?rq=1. How did you configure OpenGL support for Qt?

Comment: @Rethunk There was a bug with projection matrix. The problem is solved now.

Comment: glad you were able to fix it with a matrix tweak. Having the pictures posted may help someone else in the future. Good luck with the rest of your implementation.