# errors about QOpenGLWidget

Tags: opengl, qt5

[How do I render a triangle in QOpenGLWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522637/how-do-i-render-a-triangle-in-qopenglwidget)
When I do as the link, errors happen
[errors like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3GhI.png)
mywidget.h

```
#ifndef MYWIDGET_H
#define MYWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class myWidget;
}

class myWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit myWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~myWidget();

private:
    Ui::myWidget *ui;
};

#endif // MYWIDGET_H
```

mywidget.cpp

```
#include "mywidget.h"
#include "ui_mywidget.h"

myWidget::myWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::myWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

myWidget::~myWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

oglwidget.h

```
#ifndef OGLWIDGET_H
#define OGLWIDGET_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

class OGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
public:
    OGLWidget(QWidget *parent=0);
    ~OGLWidget();
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();
};

#endif // OGLWIDGET_H
```

oglwidget.cpp

```
#include "oglwidget.h"

OGLWidget::OGLWidget(QWidget *parent)
    :QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    
}

OGLWidget::~OGLWidget()
{

}

void OGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}

void OGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
     glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
     glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
     glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0);
     glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     glVertex3f( 0.0,  0.5, 0);
     glEnd();
}

void OGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, (float)w/h, 0.01, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,0,5,0,0,0,0,1,0);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mywidget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    myWidget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQXe6.png)
Why those errors happen? Did I miss some include file? Qt Version 5.5

Comment: Don't post error text as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution
The last two lines should be added in .pro file

```
HEADERS       = glwidget.h \
            mainwindow.h
SOURCES       = glwidget.cpp \
            main.cpp \
            mainwindow.cpp
QT           += opengl
LIBS        +=  -lopengl32
LIBS        += -lglu32
```

Then the qtcreator_process_stub terminal window may show, I go to project->run->uncheck "Run in terminal"
Yes, that works! My operating system is Win10 64bit and Qt5.6 with mingw